# ActiveAdmin logout button without current_user_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We are not using devise for auth. The user and session is managed by owned app controller. Just want to show "logout" button in active admin ui - which will call a path.

```
config.logout_link_path = :login_logout_path
config.logout_link_method = :get
```

`login_logout_path` is the correct servlet path needs to be hit for logout. the controller reads all necessary args from `session`. But setting just above two in initialiser isn't making the "logout" button appear in the ActiveAdmin UI.

I am guessing it is because of no `current_user_method` - I commented following in the config.

```
  #config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

How can we show logout button without current_user_method?

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have a method in `ApplicationController` that will return a truthy value when a user is logged in (eg. by reading from the session), I think that is good enough to use instead of :current_admin_user.